# Laravel 5.4 How to reset password with sms and notifications

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have see some articles, didn't find the solution.

I know Laravel 5.4's notifications have sms via Nexmo. And Nexmo is a third party website, one sms cost €0.0442 in my country.

But we have our own sms provider, and I had make it work. Our users have to provide real name, email, mobilephone. And the mobilephone have to be verified. I wrote a simple function to do it, with the provider's api.

I would like to implement the laravel notifications, make passwords reset via sms, like emails. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The laravel password reset logic can be found in:

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/SendsPasswordResetEmails.php`.

You can override the functions in there to accomodate for your sms needs.

But since that file is in the vendor folder you have/need to add the functions to:

`app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ForgotPasswordController.php`

(functions in the ForgotPasswordController override functions in SendsPasswordResetEmails)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has built in feature for resetting password via email, you can get lot of tutorials in this regards moreover if you want to create for sms validation then you will need a table which will hold the PIN (Personal Identification Number) for particular user, so suppose you have a table named `password_pin` you need to have columns with `users_id`, `pin`, `validated_at`, Now once you send a sms you can insert the data into these table and while verifying you can place updated with the validated at, you need to have logic where you want to have PIN to be validated once or can be verified more than once. As the validation happens you can show a form for updating the password and can update the password through those.

**Note:** You can must have a logic of validation in mind to conclude the architecture.

It will be more easier for us to guide you if you provide us the code. Hope this helps.